# Access to various @RequestMapping from method

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC i have

```
@RequestMapping({ "foo", "bar" })
public String method() {...
```

This method works with mappings "foo" or "bar". 
How to know in a method which one of two mappings worked? Like:

```
System.out.println("Your mapping is" + mapping)
```

gets me

```
Your mapping is bar
```

`@PathVariable` is unsuitable. Or maybe set restrictions on the possible values? How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RequestContextHolder` for this in your parameters:

```
@RequestMapping({ "foo", "bar" })
public void method(RequestContextHolder rqh) {

    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    String currentReqUri = attr.getRequest().getRequestURI();

    System.out.println("Your mapping is" + currentReqUri)
}
```